# Evaluate $\int_0^a \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This would be $\ln(a)-\ln(0)$. Because $\ln(0)$ is undefined, is this integral undefined too?

Comment: You should probably take a limit instead.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 9):

That's an incorrect reasoning. Note that as $\frac 1x$ is unbounded as $x\to 0$,

$$\int_0^a \frac 1x \,dx$$

is an improper integral. So the definition is

$$\int_0^a \frac 1x \, dx:= \lim_{c\to 0^+} \int_c^a \frac 1x \,dx$$

should the limit exists. But

$$\int_c^a \frac 1x \,dx = \ln a - \ln c$$

does not have a limit as $c\to 0^+$. Thus the integral is undefined.

Comment: Sorry if off topic, but I get this integral in a problem in electrostatics. I didn't get any useful answers on physics forums. I need to find electric potential on a point which lies on a center of a uniformly charged rod (point $A(0,0)$)with charge $Q$ and length $2a$. Looking at half of a rod, I am getting $dV_A=\frac{dQ}{4\pi\epsilon_0x}$ This gives $V_A=\frac{Q'}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^a \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx$ Could someone help?

Comment: The electric potential is defined such that $E=-\mathrm{grad}V$. So in your situation, you got (provided that the charge is independant of the distance $x$) $V=kQ'\ln(x)+C$ with $k$ and $C$ two constants. As $x\to 0$, $|V|\to +\infty$ (as the electric field $E$).